# pybitflyerというパッケージをインストールしようとするとImportError: cannot import name 'DependencyWarning'が出ます

Tags: python, anaconda, pip

#### 前提・実現したいこと

python3.6.3(anaconda3)でpybitflyerというパッケージをインストールしようとしています。

(参考)
bitFlyer LightningのAPIをPythonから使えるパッケージ「pybitflyer」を作りました
http://wolfin.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/08/29/010112

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
(C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3) C:\Users\keigo>pip install pybitflyer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ImportError: cannot import name 'DependencyWarning'
```

#### 試したこと

- エラーメッセージの検索⇒解決出来ませんでした。

  - [ImportError: cannot import name 'DependencyWarning' #80](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot/issues/80)
  - [Pythonで「DependencyWarning」と表示される](https://teratail.com/questions/97086)

[追記]
コメントでのやりとりを試したことにまとめました

#### 他のパッケージのインストールを試してみる

残念ながらほかのパッケージも出来ませんでした。また、pip -vを実行しても下記のようになりました。

```
 C:\Users\keigo>pip -v Traceback (most recent call last): File 
 "C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module> 
 from pip import main File "C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3\lib\site-
 packages\pip_init_.py", line 21, in <module> from 
 pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import 
 DependencyWarning ImportError: cannot import name 'DependencyWarning'
```

#### pip自体をアンインストールして再インストールしてみる

インストールされました。python3.6に同梱されていたものと思っていたのですが、入っていなかったのかもれません。

#### pipをインストール後に行いましたが、やはりエラーが出てしまいました。

```
(C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3) C:\Users\keigo>pip install pybitflyer 
Traceback (most recent call last): File 
"C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 11, in <module> 
load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')() File 
"C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources_in‌​it_.py", 
line 570, in load_entry_point return 
get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name) File 
"C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources_in‌​it_.py", 
line 2751, in load_entry_point return ep.load() File 
"C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources_init_.py", 
line 2405, in load return self.resolve() File 
"C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources_in‌​it_.py", 
line 2411, in resolve module = import__(self.module_name, fromlist=
['_name'], level=0) File "C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\pip__init_.py", line 21, in <module> from 
pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import 
DependencyWarning ImportError: cannot import name 'DependencyWarning'
```

#### 補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)

python3.6.3

Comment: その pip を使って、他のパッケージはインストールできますか?

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！
残念ながらほかのパッケージも出来ませんでした。また、pip -vを実行しても下記のようになりました。

C:\Users\keigo>pip -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ImportError: cannot import name 'DependencyWarning'

PATHが通っていない、という現象でしょうか？
初心者でして、非常に初歩的な問題でしたらすいません。

Answer (score 1):

手元で再現が出来ないので解決の手助けになりそうな項目を下にあげてみました。

#### pipのversionを上げてみる

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
```

[Python Tips：pip そのものをアップデートしたい](http://www.lifewithpython.com/2015/07/pip-upgrade-itself.html)

#### pip自体をアンインストールして再インストールしてみる

```
$ pip uninstall pip

$ easy_install pip
```

[ImportError: cannot import name DependencyWarning #164](https://github.com/infobyte/faraday/issues/164)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
_pip自体をアンインストールして再インストールしてみる_
　⇒インストールされました。python3.6に同梱されていたものと思っていたのですが、入っていなかったのかもれません。

_pybitflyerのpip install_
　⇒pipをインストール後に行いましたが、やはりエラーが出てしまいました。。（次のコメントに記載します）

Comment: (C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3) C:\Users\keigo>pip install pybitflyer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 570, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2751, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3\lib\site-

Comment: packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2405, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2411, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\keigo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ImportError: cannot import name 'DependencyWarning'

Comment: 解決しました！どうやらpythonとanacondaを一緒にインストールしていたのが問題だったようです。アドバイス頂きましてありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

どうやらpythonとanacondaを一緒にインストールしていたのが問題だったようです。環境を整理した所解決しました。

<sub>-- この回答は、[質問者さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26149/osakesuki)の[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/39495/pybitflyer%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%82%92%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%97%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8importerror-cannot-import-name-dependencywarni#comment40037_39517)を元にした回答です。</sub>